# Javascript toggle checkboxes no longer visible after pressing "back" on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, refresh, toggle

I am having a problem with checkboxes. I have a series of photos in a form. Each photo has a checkbox. If a photo's checkbox is checked, a div associated with the photo is revealed using .show().

That works fine, and I am able to submit the form. However, if I press "back" on the browser to go back to the set of photos, the checkboxes are still checked, but the div associated with it is no longer visible.

What do I need to do in order to make sure the the checked photos still have visible divs even when going "back" to the page?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  var dataID = $(this).attr("id");
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#content"+dataID).show();
  }
  else {
    $("#content"+dataID).hide();
  }
});  

});
```

and the form is something like this:

```
<form>
<input name="box1" id="box1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="box2" id="box2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="box3" id="box3" type="checkbox" />
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try displaying the images for checked divs on page load, i.e. something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  // ... your code ...
});  

$(':checkbox').each(function() {
  var dataID = $(this).attr("id");
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#content"+dataID).show();
  }
  else {
    $("#content"+dataID).hide();
  }
}); 

});
```

**Cleaner Version**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() { checkImage($(this)); });
    $(':checkbox').each(function() { checkImage($(this)); });
});
function checkImage(_checkBox) {
    var dataID = _checkBox.attr("id");
    if(_checkBox.is(':checked')) {
        $("#content"+dataID).show();
    }
    else {
        $("#content"+dataID).hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        ToggleContent($(this));
    });

    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        ToggleContent($(this));
    });

    function ToggleContent(chkbox) {
        var dataID = chkbox.attr("id");
        if (chkbox.is(':checked')) {
            $("#content" + dataID).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#content" + dataID).hide();
        }
    }
});​
```